# Reference for theorem bounding distances of values of uniformly continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, continuity, uniform-continuity

I think I proved the following theorem, but the proof is pretty long. So I thought maybe there is a reference for it because the statement seems standard. Does anyone know such a reference? Thank you!

*Theorem:*
Let $(X,d_X), (Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces, $X$ be convex, and $f \colon X\to Y$ be uniformly continuous. Then there is a function $\varepsilon\colon [0;\infty) \to [0;\infty)$, which is concave, continuous in $0$ and has the properties that $\varepsilon(0) = 0$ and, for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$, it is
$$
d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2)) \le \varepsilon(d_X(x_1,x_2)).
$$

Comment: Sorry, I found it finally: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity#Special_moduli_of_continuity I just didn't know the appropriate words to search for it.